# PostgreSQL Криво работает полнотекстовый поиск

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Имеется СУБД Postgres.

Полнотекстовый поиск умеет только сводить запрос к слову, лежащему в словаре russian.dict (там лежит "пиццерия"). Т.е. забьешь "пиццерии" - он поймет, что имелась в виду "пиццерия" и найдет, однако в обратную сторону не работает. Например он не находит, если в базе имеется запись "сеть пиццерий", хоть как забивай, потому что ее НЕТ в словаре. 
Если много слов, вот в схеме:

Если запросить "в пиццерию" НАХОДИТ "пиццерия", но НЕ НАХОДИТ "в пиццерию", если такая запись в БД имеется

Решения, которые я пробовал:

1) По умолчанию на сервере, в отличие от локалки стоит локаль для БД en_EN. Пробовал менять на ru_Ru

2) Скачал собственные словари russian.dict и russian.affix (russian.stop уже был изначально) и создал конфигурацию при помощи

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY russian_ispell (

TEMPLATE = ispell,

DictFile = russian,

AffFile = russian,

StopWords = russian

);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION ru (COPY=russian);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION ru ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word WITH russian_ispell, russian_stem;
```

Comment: неужели для решения придется создавать резервку всего кластера и нести на сервер? да и сработает ли это вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, не правильно был составлен SQL запрос.
До этого был

```
SELECT field FROM table 
    WHERE to_tsvector('ru', field)
    @@ plainto_tsquery('some_text_to_search')
```

А для полноценной функциональности необходимо было указать конфигурацию языка не только для целевого поля, но и для тела запроса. Т.е.

```
SELECT field FROM table 
        WHERE to_tsvector('ru', field)
        @@ plainto_tsquery('ru', 'some_text_to_search')
```